# Real Time Data Sync in iOS and Android application

Tags: android, ios, synchronization

In my application (iOS and Android), I have to create sync process in which changes in one device (suppose iOS) reflect the same on other one (suppose Android) I.e. something like real time method callback on other device with data change. Also is it ok if I try to create XMPP server for this?. I know it is use for real time messaging thing but just to reflect changes on other device can we use this? Plus if you are going to suggest third party API then preferably free one.

Comment: This type of "How should I tackle my app" question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use AWS Cognito. But it is not free.